# Accessing SQS **delayed** messages with Boto3?

Tags: boto3

On AWS, when my job fails for external reasons, I put them back in the queue with an increasing delay.

I'd like to run a script on the currently delayed messages but I couldn't find a way to access them using Boto3.

Is there a way to do so? It would be only to read them, no deletion or altering would occur.

Comment: You can't access delayed messages in an SQS queue until the delay expires. That's the entire point of setting the delay.

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of `peek` way, like on Redis. But yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!